Show that for a given monic kernel polynomial sequence there exist infinitely many monic orthogonal polynomial squences.
I'm currently working through the T. Chihara "Introduction into ortghogonal polynomials" book, and the problem 7.2 of the book is to proof the property from the title. In particular:

For a fixed $\kappa$, a monic OPS [orthogonal polynomial sequence] uniquely determines {$P_n^*(\kappa, x)$}. Show that, however, there are infinitely many different monic OPS whose monic KPS [kernel polynomial sequence] with $K$-parameter is {$P_n^*(\kappa, x)$}.

The KPS is defined as
$$
P_n^*(\kappa, x) = (x-\kappa)^{-1}\left[P_{n+1}(x) - \frac{P_{n-1}(\kappa)}{P_n(\kappa)}P_n(x)\right] = \lambda_1\dots\lambda_{n+1}[P_n(\kappa)^{-1}]\Sigma_{k=0}^n p_k(k)p_k(x)
$$
where $P_k$ are corresponding orthogonal monic polynomials, $p_k$ are corresponding orthonormal polynomials and $\lambda_n$ are corresponding coefficients from the three-term recurrence relation: $$
P_n = (x-c_n)P_{n-1} - \lambda_n P_{n-2}
$$
The numbers and polynomials are considered complex.

It is unclear to me how the infinitely many corresponding MOPS can exist, since the KPS definition leaves seemingly no space for this. The proper start might be:
"Suppose there exists another MOPS {$Q_n$}, whose KPS is given above. Then:
$$
Q_{n+1}(x) - \frac{Q_{n+1}(\kappa)}{Q_{n}(\kappa)}Q_n(x) = P_{n+1}(x) - \frac{P_{n-1}(\kappa)}{P_n(\kappa)}P_n(x)
$$
and both $Q_{n+1}$ and $P_{n+1}$ have their highest coefficient fixed to 1."
How should I proceed from there however? I have tried to find an interpolation between two different polynomials for each $n$, but I haven't managed to define it properly.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
